# Error 500: illegal characters in path

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to post some data to an EndPoint, resulting in response - `illegal characters in path`

RootDTO = the DTO structure, I pasted the example XML to [this site](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/)
So I believe it's not the problem.

**Am I doing something wrong?**

```
private Boolean ApiRequest(string order, string path)
{
    var t = string.Empty;
    var Obj_response = new RootDTO();

    byte[] requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(order);

    HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(path)) as HttpWebRequest;
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.Accept = "application/xml";
    req.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
    req.ContentLength = requestData.Length;

    using (Stream post = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        post.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);
    }

    try
    {
        //XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootDTO));

        using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            string resJson = string.Empty;

            if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var ms = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), UTF8Encoding.UTF8);
                t = ms.ReadToEnd(); // <-----t contains "illegal characters in path"

                return true;
            }
            else
            { // error occured?
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        // error during APIrequest
        var resp = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: So, what does `path` contain and why do you think it's valid? What you're reading there is a server response, so there's something wrong with your request.

Comment: Path is the URL endpoint

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. The server is telling you the requested path is invalid, so there's something you're not telling us. Do you have an example of a request that _does_ work, and did you try to rebuild that exact request using this code?

Comment: @EranMeir Yes, we understand what the path variable represents - but what does it *contain*?

Comment: No, i don't have an example of a working code. 
the path itself is right (i am getting somthing in response)

Comment: OK one final time before the closehounds eat you - what is *in* the path variable at the point you get the 500 error?

Comment: So, whose endpoint is it? Did you try building a proper request from documentation, for example using Fiddler? If we don't know what a proper request is supposed to look like, we can't tell you how to fix this code. The error is pretty self-explanatory: you're providing an incorrect request path, or the server is returning that error because there's something else wrong with the request.

Comment: path = http://mail.X.com/Planweb/xmllistener.aspx

Comment: @CodeCaster, i am sorry but i didn't know that path relate to the url itself, i thought it related to something else in the request

Comment: So the *endpoint* gives this error? Then you are sending erroneous data and that cannot be deduced from the code.

Comment: @Eran it doesn't _have_ to mean that, but without any info on the actual web service you're calling, we can't answer this. It may as well be the XML data, or a coding error on their site. In fact, you're saying in your title it's a 500 error, so the most likely is that they made an error somewhere. This error still could be triggered by what the XML contains, for example if they try to save a file based on a path built from an XML element's value.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen as it stated in my qeustion`t` holds the error, so it is the response

Comment: @CodeCaster - can i post something that will help you to understand it better?

Comment: Possibly an ASP.NET configuration issue - see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881877/mvc-url-request-illegal-characters-in-path

Comment: The documentation of the service you're calling, or the XML data you're posting would help a lot.

Comment: Yes, so then you check the data you send to the endpoint based on the endpoint documentation. It's not a problem with this code, it's the request.

Comment: Also, can someone explain to me, why did i got an "-1" ?

Comment: @CodeCaster - This is the full response `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cXML.org/schemas/cXML/1.1.009/cXML.dtd"><cXML payloadID="PlanWeb" xml:lang="en-US" timestamp="3/6/2016 7:41:17 AM"><Response><Status code="500" text="Illegal characters in path." /><PlanJobID>Failed</PlanJobID>
</Response></cXML>` - It helps?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was easy to solve - there were a problem in the XML

the thing that cause the problem was:

```
<url>
http://www.domain.com
</url>
```

I changed it to:

```
 <url>http://www.domain.com</url>
```

that fixed it.